# put UIImage object into system cache?

Tags: ios, caching, uiimage

If I create a UIImage object in-app, is it possible to put it into the UIImage image cache with a name?  Basically, I would later want to retrieve it with a call to imageNamed: unless the system had thrown it away, in which case I would recreate it.

Answer (score 1):

If you create an object using the `[UIImage imageNamed:"somename.png"]` it automatically caches and will only release it if there is a memory warning notification or hopefully when you suspend your application.

If you want more control over it I would suggest any of these methods:

- Storing into someDictionary and storing it into the userDefaults. e.g. {"imageName":"the name.format","imageData":someImageData"}. Heck you can even store everything in an array of dictionaries.
- enumerated array: store all necessary images onto an array in the user defaults. and the names into an enumerated typedef. Just match the string to an array index.

Note, I assume that the images have static names. If you change the image names constantly, I would not suggest caching at all.